# Infopath validations on text box

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

Is there any way to make a textbox display certain values once a checkbox is ticked?
[image]

The textbox with Asset Master Data, once the "Single Request" is ticked, it should display "Asset Master Data - Single Request"

or if mass upload checkbox it should display  "Asset Master Data - Mass Upload Request"

Answer (score 0):

Create a action rule on each checkbox. Leave the condition to execute when they are clicked.

Set the action to set field 'Master Data type' to "Asset Master Data - Single Request" for the first checkbox and then "Asset Master Data - Mass Upload Request" for the second checkbox rule.